# How to get my onClick method in android to work properly?

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

In my program i want it to display a light on the screen after a button is clicked.
This works with just straight putting it onCreate so as soon as the app starts the light appears but when i put the same method in my onClick for a Button it doesn't seem to work.

```
public class LightFlashGame extends Activity {

public static final int LIGHT_DIAM = 15;

final Lights lightModel = new Lights();

LightFlashView lightView;

private static int light = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    lightView = new LightFlashView(this, lightModel);

    //makeLights(lightModel, lightView, Color.RED); !!!Works when method is called here

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_light_flash_game);
    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root)).addView(lightView, 0);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack)).setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent backScreen = new Intent(LightFlashGame.this, LightFlashMain.class);
                   startActivity(backScreen);
                } });

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override public void onClick(View v){
                makeLights(lightModel, lightView, Color.RED); !!!But not here       
                }
            });    
}

/** Install a context menu. */
@Override public void onCreateContextMenu(
    ContextMenu menu,
    View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}

/** Respond to a context menu selection. */
@Override public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.light_flash_main, menu);
    return true;
}

void makeLights(Lights lights, LightFlashView light, int color){
    lights.addLight(
            LIGHT_DIAM + (75),
            LIGHT_DIAM + (75),
            color,
            LIGHT_DIAM);

}
```

}

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LightFlashGame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRound"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnBack"
        android:text="Round : " 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LightFlash" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Back" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Score : "
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you also post your layout? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that the button is being clicked? Maybe include a `Toast` in `onClick`?

Comment: button click registers fine ive checked it using logcat

Comment: Did you get this thing working yet? I'm very curious as to what your glitch was.

Answer (score 1):

your method is not public make it public and then try to access this now!

```
public void makeLights(Lights lights, LightFlashView light, int color){
    lights.addLight(
            LIGHT_DIAM + (75),
            LIGHT_DIAM + (75),
            color,
            LIGHT_DIAM);

}
```

couldn't find any error in your code, try to change it like this:

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override public void onClick(View v){
                lightView = new LightFlashView(this, lightModel);
                makeLights(lightModel, lightView, Color.RED);

                }
            });
```

Comment: "this" won't work as expected in your new code, @Hamad, as it is inside an anonymous class.

Comment: sorry that's my mistake, use getBaseContext() , not this keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Change your call to `makeLights()` in `onClick()` to the following:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    LightFlashGame.this.makeLights(lightModel, lightView, Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: still not doing anything

Comment: Hmm... That's curious. Is your IDE giving you any warnings?

Comment: Also, you might try cleaning and re-building your project. Seems like at least one of our answers should work.